# How to open iOS QRCode / Android QRCode with params

Tags: javascript, android, ios, qr-code

I would like to connect to a WiFi through my browser interface (using Javascript), I was told it is not possible. But maybe it is possible if I could open the internal QRCode reader and giving it the formatted information (bellow).

`WIFI:S:{ssid};T:{type};P:{password};H:{hidden};;`

I thought that maybe it was usable through an custom URI scheme, but I didn't find it neither on iOS nor on Android.

How to invoke QRCode Scanner from device with custom parameters to give it a string representation (the one above) ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to do - what does 'connect to a WiFi' mean exactly here? I can't see why it would be made possible through using a QR code - which just gives you text - if it isn't possible from the browser.

Comment: Hello @AHaworth , when scanning a QRCode from phone, it can connect to WiFi. My use case is all on browser end, I would like to make a user connect to a wifi (with consent) using any method, I had this idea it invoke the QRCode Scanner with parameters to do so, which is probably more possible ?